# Problem with line breaking using \\ in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, tikz-trees

Here is my code, which was compiled by pdflatex.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]\Tree
[.(0,0)
    [.(0,1)
        [.(1,1)
            [.(1,2)\\$\downarrow$\\(2,0)
                [.(3,0)
                    [.(4,0)\\$\downarrow$\\\textcolor{olive}{(1,3)} ]
                    [.\textcolor{olive}{(3,1)} ]
                ]
                [.\textcolor{cyan}{(2,1)} ]
            ]
            [.\textcolor{cyan}{(2,1)} ]
        ]
        [.(0,2)
            [.(0,3)
                [.(1,3)\\$\downarrow$\\\textcolor{purple}{(4,0)} ]
                [.\textcolor{purple}{(0,4)} ]
            ]
            [.(1,2)\\$\downarrow$\\(2,0)
                [.(3,0)
                    [.(4,0)\\$\downarrow$\\\textcolor{olive}{(1,3)} ]
                    [.\textcolor{olive}{(3,1)} ]
                ]
                [.\textcolor{cyan}{(2,1)} ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [.(1,0)
        [.(2,0)\\$\downarrow$\\(1,2)
            [.(1,3)\\$\downarrow$\\\textcolor{purple}{(4,0)} ]
            [.\textcolor{blue}{(2,2)} ]
        ]
        [.(1,1)
            [.(1,2)\\$\downarrow$\\(2,0)
                [.(3,0)
                    [.(4,0)\\$\downarrow$\\\textcolor{olive}{(1,3)} ]
                    [.\textcolor{olive}{(3,1)} ]
                ]
                [.\textcolor{cyan}{(2,1)} ]
            ]
            [.\textcolor{cyan}{(2,1)} ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

According to the documentation of `tikz-qtree` package, the use of `\\` for line breaking in nodes is possible. But the code above can't compile correctly. If I change the parts containing `\\` it'll work.

Why is it so? How can I break lines in a node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks as You haven't added

```
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
```

after

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
```

before calling `\Tree`.
Also just in case check `\pgfversion` if its > 2.1 as documentation says

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\Tree
[.(0,0)
    [.(0,1)
        [.(1,1)
            [.(1,2)\\$\downarrow$\\(2,0)
                [.(3,0)
                    [.(4,0)\\$\downarrow$\\\textcolor{olive}{(1,3)} ]
                    [.\textcolor{olive}{(3,1)} ]
                ]
                [.\textcolor{cyan}{(2,1)} ]
            ]
            [.\textcolor{cyan}{(2,1)} ]
        ]
        [.(0,2)
            [.(0,3)
                [.(1,3)\\$\downarrow$\\\textcolor{purple}{(4,0)} ]
                [.\textcolor{purple}{(0,4)} ]
            ]
            [.(1,2)\\$\downarrow$\\(2,0)
                [.(3,0)
                    [.(4,0)\\$\downarrow$\\\textcolor{olive}{(1,3)} ]
                    [.\textcolor{olive}{(3,1)} ]
                ]
                [.\textcolor{cyan}{(2,1)} ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [.(1,0)
        [.(2,0)\\$\downarrow$\\(1,2)
            [.(1,3)\\$\downarrow$\\\textcolor{purple}{(4,0)} ]
            [.\textcolor{blue}{(2,2)} ]
        ]
        [.(1,1)
            [.(1,2)\\$\downarrow$\\(2,0)
                [.(3,0)
                    [.(4,0)\\$\downarrow$\\\textcolor{olive}{(1,3)} ]
                    [.\textcolor{olive}{(3,1)} ]
                ]
                [.\textcolor{cyan}{(2,1)} ]
            ]
            [.\textcolor{cyan}{(2,1)} ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `level distance=50pt` for better result